# Websocket connection failed giving error 1006 and connection closed in HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, websocket

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

function WebSocketTest()
         {

var ws = $.gracefulWebSocket("ws://localhost/Node/");

ws.onopen=function(ev){

```
alert('Connected to server');
```

};

ws.send("Client is sending message");

ws.onmessage = function (event) {

var messageFromServer = event.data;

alert('Message' +messageFromServer);

};

ws.onerror=function(ev){

```
alert('Error' +ev.code);
```

};

}

```
  <div >

     <a href="javascript:WebSocketTest()">Run WebSocket</a>

  </div>
```

Here I have also added gracefulWebSocket library but  Stackoverflow just removed it .I am using chrome browser for this Please help me Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You include js file from there? https://github.com/ffdead/jquery-graceful-websocket

What console tells you? (Developer Tools - F12 key shortcut on Chrome).

Comment: There are two errors  1'st is  TypeError: $(...).unload is not a function                                                                            $(window).unload(function () { ws.close(); ws = null });  and 2nd one is    Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at ws://localhost/Node/.            var  ws = window.WebSocket ? new WebSocket(url) : new FallbackSocket();

Comment: There is one more thing  is that I have already downloaded jquery-graceful-websocket into my Node folder inside htdocs

Comment: You are using Node.js to services WebSockets on backend side?

Comment: No I am using xampp server in windows 7